# How to make Rx value sinks aware of outdated responses?

Tags: swift, concurrency, system.reactive, race-condition, rx-swift

I have a live search with autocompletion in-place (i.e. the text box contents change).

I have a request/response mechanism: like `.rx.text.flatMapLatest(requestSuggestion)`. But the result is `merge`d with 2 other sources of changes, all 3 of them `Driver`s, though (on main thread, sharing replay, not erroring-out).

When binding the result back to the text field, there was a minimal time window where the user can type the next character but gets the suggestion for the last typing. **So the response consumption lacks behind a tiny bit. I want to get rid of that race condition.**

#### Request enumeration approach

I figured it'd be good to discard not rely on `.flatMapLatest` here on client side but make the component's value sink check for *out-of-date*-ness like you do in a server/client environment. In other words, I enumerate requests, the poor man's time stamp. Now I have a `.rx.contentChange` where the type has the text value + a `requestNumber`.

It seems to work, but I cannot come up with a useful design of the sink. Its overall setup looks clunky and the `disposable` in the capture group is ... not so good.

What I am aiming for is a setup similar to `Observable.create` where you can combine disposables, only `Observers`/sinks don't have this kind of stuff.

```
// Request and response are similar to:
struct Request  { let content: String; let requestNumber: Int }
struct Response { let content: String; let requestNumber: Int }

// Hacky sink that works, but meh:
public var enumeratedResponseSink: AnyObserver<Response> {

    // A reference to the ControlEvent that the client code is observing.
    // Using Driver here because I want to make this a UIBindingObserver later.
    let requestNumbers = self.requests.asDriver()
        .map { $0.requestNumber }
    let publish = PublishSubject<Response>()

    let disposable = publish.asDriver(onErrorDriveWith: .empty())
        .withLatestFrom(requestNumbers) { response, number in (response, number) }
        .filter { response, latestRequestNumber in response.requestNumber >= latestRequestNumber }
        .map { response, _ in response.content }
        .drive(self.content) // is a UIBindingObserver

    // Look, I put a strong reference to the disposable inside so it 
    // doesn't go away, but man that doesn't feel right:
    return AnyObserver { [disposable] event in

        guard case .next(let response) = event else { return }

        publish.onNext(response)
    }
}
```

So this is my attempt at letting the component know from inside the `Observer` declaration what it *itself* expects the next response number to be.

- How I can make this freshness check work better?
- Is this a proper approach at all, or do you have a better idea to solve the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that, instead of using a "request number", you should include the text that was used to generate the response. When the text box receives an auto-fill response, it can compare what is currently in it with the response that was received and only use the response if the response extends it's current user input...

You might have to make a custom text box for this that can distinguish between user input and input that comes from a request response. I expect you have already done that in order to show the text in different fonts/colors for user consumption.

Or have I completely misunderstood what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is possible and it would work. Autocompletions come as replacements (made of a base + suggestion), so I'd have to change that or sacrifice the ability to set the text field to an arbitrary autocompletion programmatically, like in an interactive tutorial, because 2 different programmatic changes for different strings would not work. I'll have to weigh the pros/cons some more.